# How can i download Tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying for like the past week yet I can't get it to work, I've been copy and pasting the exact same text and I don't know what I really have to do.

I have tried to do this but i keep getting this error and im just trying to install it

[image: image:]

with "npm install -D tailwindcss"

and following the guides on the website, I've downloaded the CLI yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you [install node](https://nodejs.org/en/download)? If not you need to start there.

Answer (score 1):

To install `Tailwind` as per the [Official documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation), you need to install `Nodejs` and `npm` into your machine. To do this, depending on your machine and OS, get the download link from [NodeJS official website](https://nodejs.org/en).

After installation, you will need to restart your `command prompt` or `terminal`. Then navigate to the directory you want tailwind CSS installed:

```
cd c:\app_folder

npm install -D tailwindcss
```

Comment: i installed node js and ran it and dropped the CLI in the node js folder yet it doesnt work

Comment: What is the output when you run the command?